# ListViewItem style doesn't work correctly

Tags: listview, uwp, listviewitem

I have a strange issue today. I have the following ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          x:Name="listviewZoomedIn"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewCustomItemStyle}"/>
```

And the ItemContainerStyle named "ListViewCustomItemStyle" is the following:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewTransmitterItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter
      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
      SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
      CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
      FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
      FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
      PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
      PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
      SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
      PressedBackground="Orange"
      SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
      DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
      DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
      ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
      ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      CheckMode="Inline"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this style I just changed the PressedBackground color.
And this work only for the first click on an item. Then, the pressed background is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under the `PressedBackground` property that you changed to `Orange`, is the `SelectedPressedBackground`property.
This defines the pressed state color for an item that is selected. Change that to `Orange` or any color that you need and it should work.

Comment: Logic... Thanks to you